# Checked attribute not changing accordingly for radio button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently doing a `radio button` toggling. I am trying to do out something like this

[image: radio button toggling]

However, when I do this in C# and changes the radio button to ASP.NET controls, the `checked=true` attribute does not change until `PostBack` happens. So when the attribute does not change, the `OnCheckedChange` event does not trigger as well, which is the current issue.

I tried doing and I realized the problem is with `data-toggle="buttons"`. However, without that `data-toggle="buttons"`, the function would be incomplete.

Is there a way to make the `checked=true` attribute work even if there's `data-toggle="buttons"`?

Here's my sample code

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 4%;">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="currentOption" runat="server" Text="Current Batch" Checked="true" CssClass="btn btn-primary active btn-lg" GroupName="currentPastOption" OnCheckedChanged="currentPastOption_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="pastOption" runat="server" Text="Past Batch" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" GroupName="currentPastOption" OnCheckedChanged="currentPastOption_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </div>

        </div>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void currentPastOption_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if (currentOption.Checked)
            {
              ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "onPageLoad();", true);
              loadCurrentData();
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "onPageLoad();", true);
            loadPastData();
        }
        }
```